# SAP HANA Smart Data Access: Can't count rows of virtual Table (Hive)

Tags: hive, odbc, hortonworks-data-platform, hana

I have a HANA Express VM which I want to interact with a Hadoop cluster. I have a Hive table which I connected via Smart Data Access (SDA) to HANA. Everything works fine with the virtual table, I can use SAP HANA Studio for querying the Hive data (`select` statements), but when I try to count the table rows, I get an exception in my HANA Studio:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM "SYSTEM"."orctable";
```

leads to following exception:

```
Could not execute 'SELECT count(*) FROM "SYSTEM"."orctable"' in 602 ms 558 µs . 
SAP DBTech JDBC: [403]: internal error: Error opening the cursor for the remote database [Hortonworks][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message: 'ExecuteStatement finished with operation state: ERROR_STATE'. for query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HIVE.default.orctable orctable "
```

I also added a new virtual table using uppercase letters for the virtual table name (`ORCTABLE`) in HANA, as HANA uses uppercase as default, same error! Other tries:

- `SELECT count(1) FROM "SYSTEM"."orctable"`
- `SELECT count(columnA) FROM "SYSTEM"."orctable"`
- `SELECT count(A.*) FROM "SYSTEM"."orctable" as A`
- ...

When I call a `select count(*) from orctable` from my Hive UI, everythigns works fine.

I also found this tutorial where a `SELECT COUNT(*)` is made against a virtual Hive table: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/06/02/sap-hana-smart-data-access3-how-to-access-hadoop-data-through-hive-with-sda/

I'm using the latest VM of HANA Express, the Hive ODBC driver v2.1.7 for SUSE 12 and a HDP 2.5 Cluster with Hive 1.2.1.

Has someone else this problem or a guess why this doesn't work or already a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM "SYSTEM"."orctable");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the statement in the error log from Hive ui?

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HIVE.default.orctable orctable

And is a simple select with no count working?

Comment: A simple `select * from "SYSTEM"."orctable"` is working. The command `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "HIVE.default.orctable" "orctable"` brings the exception `SAP DBTech JDBC: [259]: invalid table name:  Could not find table/view HIVE.default.orctable in schema SYSTEM: line 1 col 22 (at pos 21)`

Comment: Can you try SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HIVE.default.orctable orctable with no double quotes?